# QT read spreadsheets (Excel) file

Tags: c++, excel, qt

I need to read a spreadsheet in Excel using Qt in order to import data in a db.

I can read the data using:

```
qDebug() << "Open excel.." << endl;
QSqlDatabase excel = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
excel.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=" + file);

if(excel.open())
{
    int cont = 0;
    QSqlQuery query("select * from [Sheet1"  + "$]");
    while(query.next())
    {
       QString column1= query.value(0).toString();
       QString column2= query.value(1).toString();
       QString column3= query.value(2).toString();
       QString column4= query.value(3).toString();
       QString column5= query.value(4).toString();

        qDebug("('', %d, %d, %d, \"%s\"),",
               column2.toInt(),
               column3.toInt(),
               column4.toInt(),
               column5.toStdString().c_str());

        cont++;
    }

    QString reg = "Regs: " + cont;
    qDebug() << reg;

}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Can't open file (Excel)" << endl;
}
```

This method works but I must to known the name(s) of the sheets in the excel file. I need read the file dynamically.

I have been reading about QAxObject class but I can't find a working example.

```
QAxWidget excel("Excel.Application");
excel.setProperty("Visible", true);

QAxObject * workbooks = excel.querySubObject("WorkBooks");
workbooks->dynamicCall("Open (const QString&)", file);
```

Here get the error:

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'class QAxObject'
    workbooks->dynamicCall("Open (const QString&)", QString("C:/test7.xls"));
          ^
```

Someone knows or have a functional example?? I will appreciate it a lot.

Gretings.

Comment: should be `workbooks_1->dynamicCall` not `workbooks->dynamicCall` and try to in clude QAxObject header file